# How match multiple column values and extract corresponding cell values in Excel

Tags: excel

Sheet 1

```
Cust Visit  DATE        TIME

201 Day 1   11-Jul-17   11:15

201 Day 1   11-Jul-17   11:18

201 Day 1   11-Jul-17   11:20

201 Day 3   13-Jul-17   11:30

201 Day 3   13-Jul-17   11:32

201 Day 3   13-Jul-17   11:34

201 Day 7   17-Jul-17   11:20

201 Day 7   17-Jul-17   11:22

201 Day 7   17-Jul-17   11:24

201 Day 10  20-Jul-17   11:30

201 Day 10  20-Jul-17   11:32

201 Day 10  20-Jul-17   11:34

201 Day 14  24-Jul-17   11:15

201 Day 14  24-Jul-17   11:17

201 Day 14  24-Jul-17   11:19

202 Day 1   11-Jul-17   11:20

202 Day 1   11-Jul-17   11:22
................
.............
```

Sheet 2

```
RefC RVisit RDATE       RefTIME

201 Day 1   11-Jul-17   9:30

201 Day 3   13-Jul-17   9:30

201 Day 7   17-Jul-17   9:30

201 Day 10  20-Jul-17   9:30

201 Day 14  24-Jul-17   9:30

202 Day 1   11-Jul-17   9:35

202 Day 3   13-Jul-17   9:35
...............
.....
```

First set of columns in excel  show customer ID visit date and time for their survey participation.

The second set of columns shows the same Customer IDs shared by reference customers and similar details. Both are in the same sheet of excel.

We are to compare the time difference between reference customers and current customers of their visits. i.e. I want the values in RefTime column lined up next to the TIME column when refc matches Cust and Rvisit matches visit and date matches Rdate. The visits can be 3 per day or 2, it may vary.

I am unsure of how to approach this using formulas (`INDEX` & `MATCH` ?), and i am new to excel. Any help or intro to help me achieve this is appreciated.

Thanks !

Sorry for not being clear..For ex.  I want the Reftime below 9.30 for Refc # 201

RefC RVisit RDATE       RefTIME

201    Day 1   11-Jul-17   9:30

to appear next to TIME column for the first 3 rows of below as all details of above match (cust # wtih RefC , visit with Rvisit and date with Rdate).

Cust Visit  DATE        TIME

201 Day 1   11-Jul-17   11:15  9:30

201 Day 1   11-Jul-17   11:18  9:30

201 Day 1   11-Jul-17   11:20   9:30

Comment: The data portion of your question is a big difficult to follow.  Could you please format it or include a screenshot or something?

Comment: I have reformatted.. hope it is helpful now

Comment: it's not exactly clear what you want to put next to the TIME column as the Sheet 1 data has 4 rows with `201 Day 1   11-Jul-17` and Sheet 2 has 2 rows with different RefTIMEs `9:30 and 9:35` so how is it possible to know which refTIME goes next to which TIME?  Maybe you could give an example of what you want the formula to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It is still unclear what you want. I think you want a VLOOKUP but on more than one key. You can add a column in the Sheet2 to the left of the current columns - Assuming the RefC R Visit is Col B:
in Col 1, copy down `=B1&B2` and then you can reference this column (and its subsequent columns) in a concatenated VLOOKUP: in the cell in SHeet1 where you want the result - assuming Cust Visit is column A, you put in, say Col E, `=VLOOKUP(A2&B2,Sheet2!$A$2:$E$10000, 3, False)`

The dollar anchors are important on the second parameter. The 3 in the third parameter says match column C, the False means look for exact matches. Wrap it in an IFERROR of IF(ISNA()) if you want to avoid non-found record errors.